# form action="your-shop" : what does this mean without file extension?

Tags: html

I have seen filename(with file extension) or URL inside action attribute but never seen anything like this code below.

```
<form action="your-shop" name="shop_name_form" id="shop_name_form" method="post" onsubmit="return check_shopname(this);">
</form>
```

Here action attribute contains may be a file name but no file name extension.
What will it do when i press submit button?please explain it in details

Comment: You may also see on SO address bar there's no extension. This is because of SEO friendly...

Comment: i didn't understand what you are trying to say.explain a little bit more please.I am working it in codeigniter framework.@C-link Nepal

Answer (score 1):

It's a relative URL and will be resolved against the current URL. E.g. If the page is located at `http://example.com/current/path/foo`, the from will be submitted to `http://example.com/current/path/your-shop`.

File extensions have no meaning in a URL, how the path is processed depends on the server implementation.

Comment: I am working it in codeigniter framework.The "form" tag is in a view page.so does that mean "your-shop" redirects to a controller or to a function of a controller or to anything else?

Comment: “File extensions have no meaning in a URL” is misleading. Taken literally, it would mean that your-shop and your-shop.html have no difference. More appropriately, URLs are not filenames, and they have no “file extension” concept; the server processes the path part of a URL in the way it likes (and may, in fact, map URLs to files in a file system).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: That sounds indeed better and is what I meant.

Comment: @user3257218: I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

At first it calls the Javascript function `check_shopname();`.
If it returns false, the submit will be canceled, so maybe there is no case where true is returned, because the Admin handles all the things on the client side!

The second possibility is, that the url of the sites are modified by [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), and you get redirected to another file, for example, by adding a .html or .php extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you will take you to the following link for form submission.

`www.yourwebsite.com/your-shop`. your-shop will be appeneded to the website's URL. Since there is no folder or other directory included. As Felix has mentioned already in comments, the File extension like `.html` has no meaning here in this context of `action`.